# How to log every call to member functions of a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I want to avoid inserting console.log() statements in every method of a JavaScript class, but I want to know which members are called and which aren't by running the code and capturing debug output.

Is there any kind of hook or handler I can use, or a debugging library perhaps, so I can just modify the class or an instance in one place, and then see which members are called via the console (or similar)?

The class has a lot of members, so this would be a useful time saver for me! As well as enable me to easily turn logging on and off more easily.

My first Q.. thanks :)

Comment: The Chrome debugger has many features, including the [Javascript Call Stack Panel](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#call-stack-panel) which might interest you. This way has zero overhead and doesn't require altering the code that you are trying to observe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap all the functions on the instance. For instance, assuming `obj` is the object you want to watch:

```
function wrapObjectFunctions(obj, before, after) {
  var key, value;

  for (key in obj) {
    value = obj[key];
    if (typeof value === "function") {
      wrapFunction(obj, key, value);
    }
  }

  function wrapFunction(obj, fname, f) {
    obj[fname] = function() {
      var rv;
      if (before) {
        before(fname, this, arguments);
      }
      rv = f.apply(this, arguments); // Calls the original
      if (after) {
        after(fname, this, arguments, rv);
      }
      console.log( /*...*/ );
      return rv;
    };
  }
}
```

(`arguments` in the above, if you're not familiar with it, is a magic pseudo-array provided by JavaScript which contains the arguments that the function was called with. I know it looks like pseudo-code, but it isn't.)

**Live Example:**

```js
function Thing(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Thing.prototype.sayName = function () {
    console.log("My name is " + this.name);
};

var t = new Thing("Fred");
console.log("Before wrapping:");
t.sayName(); // My name is Fred, with no extra logging

console.log("----");

wrapObjectFunctions(
    t,
    function(fname) {
        console.log("LOG: before calling " + fname);
    },
    function(fname) {
        console.log("LOG: after calling " + fname);
    }
);

console.log("After wrapping:");
t.sayName(); // My name is Fred, with no extra logging

function wrapObjectFunctions(obj, before, after) {
    var key, value;

    for (key in obj) {
        value = obj[key];
        if (typeof value === "function") {
            wrapFunction(obj, key, value);
        }
    }

    function wrapFunction(obj, fname, f) {
        obj[fname] = function() {
            var rv;
            if (before) {
                before(fname, this, arguments);
            }
            rv = f.apply(this, arguments); // Calls the original
            if (after) {
                after(fname, this, arguments, rv);
            }
            console.log(/*...*/);
            return rv;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Really useful, thank you! BTW I changed snippet.js to use "console.log()" rather than modify the page itself.

Comment: Thanks @trincot! I have a list of these answers from before snippets had their own console that I peck away at periodically...

Comment: Hello 2015! Found this while looking for a way to do... exactly what this logger does, except automatically for all function calls. Would be interested to know your opinion on how one might apply this to all functions instead of manually wrapping each one.

Comment: @GregPettit - Hi! :-) I don't think you can, if you don't have a means of enumerating the functions (for instance, because they're properties of an object (which you could use `wrapObjectFunctions` on).